# Wordpress - Header with search form instead of description

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to insert a search form in the header of a website instead of printing the description, but with no success.

The theme doesn't have a searchform.php.

The code in the header.php is

```
    <?php
            global $page, $paged;
            wp_title('|', true, 'right');
            bloginfo('name');
$site_description = get_bloginfo('description', 'display');
            if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page()))
                echo " | $site_description";
            if ($paged >= 2 || $page >= 2)
                echo ' | ' . sprintf( __('Page %s'), max($paged, $page));
        ?>
```

I tried to manually insert `<?php get_search_form(); ?>` instead of the description code and

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
    </div>
</form>
```

but nothing worked, the website wouldn't even show anymore.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @Gowri stop useless edits, do something useful

Comment: It seems it is not full header.php code. I think you are trying to make edits in title section of header.php Please post full header.php code which theme you are using?

Comment: Yes, it's not the full header: i took the section I was trying to edit, in order to avoid long and useless code. The theme I'm using is Suburbia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized I was editing the wrong piece of code.
I put `<?php get_search_form(); ?>` in another section of the header, and it worked. Thanks anyone.

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
    </div>
</form>
```

*MUST* be placed in `searchform.php` file, if it does not exist, then create it.
Afterwards the call to `<?php get_search_form(); ?>`  will work.

Comment: Okay, I just did it. The problem is that I don't know where, in the code above, to put the php call. I want to delete the description, but if I do, the website stops working,

Comment: Nevermind, I just solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

OK, just to put it together, the correct answers are here allready:

FIRST:
You should paste

```
add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'search-form' ) );
```

to your functions.php if it's not allready in there. This helps you to activate HTML5 Support for your form. There are several other options you could choose - there you go: [Add theme support for HTML5](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support), you should look for:

```
add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'comment-list', 'comment-form', 'search-form', 'gallery', 'caption' ) );
```

credits to @Moax6629

Next: Your code belongs to the searchform.php as @bodi0 said.
Tipp: Turn on / off autocomplete:

```
<form action="" autocomplete="on">
```

and don't forget to tell google Analytics that your identifier is "s" so you could also track what your users are searching for if you're using G-Analytics. [Tutorial here](http://www.carriedils.com/wordpress-track-site-search/)

Optional: My favorite solution: You could also add an sidebar widget area in your header by placing this code:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'id-you-have-give-while-registering' ) ) : ?>
    <span id="header-widget" class="put all your css classes here" role="complementary">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'id-you-have-give-while-registering' ); ?>
    </span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So the admin could add also text or icons instead of the searchform in the header. Also you could stlye the header searchform in a different way than the searchform maybe found on the 404 Page.

Don't forget to tell wordpress about the sidebar by posting the following to your functions

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' =>__( 'Your name which will be displayed as Widget Area Name', 'youridgoeshere'),
    'id' => 'id-you-have-give-while-registering', // this ID is meant by "id-you-have-give-while-registering"
    'description' => __( 'Der Inhalt erscheint in der Kopfzeile am rechten Rand der Menüleiste.', 'youridgoeshere' ),
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</aside>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title centered">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );
```

Hope this helps you out! And sorry for all the editing, but some of my codes are not displayed and I tried my best to get them shown :(
All the best
Fab

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'search-form' ) );
```